# Is it possible to have a shared secret without any party knowing all the parts?

Tags: rsa, public-key, secret-sharing

I believe with `Shamir’s Secret Sharing Scheme`, I can create an n-part secret and distribute each of those parts to `n` parties. But the weakness is that I still know all the parts.

Is there a mechanism in which `n` parties can each have a secret that none of the other parties know, but yet have the public key be known in advance?

In asymmetric cryptography, if I have a private key, I can share the public key freely and then I can digitally sign a message proving that I have the private key for that public one. I assume something similar can be done with Samir’s SSS, but what I’m seeking is a way to do it in a distributed fashion.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The keyword is **dealer** dupe of [Shamir secret sharing with no dealer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/84143/18298) and [Secret sharing - no dealer, modifiable, verifiable](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/13185/18298)

Comment: Are you trying to have a well known (publicized) public key, and a secret-shared private key (so that no set of $t-1$ individuals ever know the private key)?  If so, yes, that's doable...

Comment: If there is a shared public key, and your goal is to have a scheme such that a threshold k of n signers are required to sign for the public key, then what you are looking for is a threshold multi-signature scheme. Is that your goal?